# How to close all windows that Selenium opens?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-rc

I am using Selenium RC to do some test now. And the driver I use is python.

But now, I faced a problem, that is: every time Selenium RC runs, and open a url, it opens 2 windows, one is for logging and the other one is for showing HTML content. But I can't close them all in script.

Here is my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*-coding:utf-8-*-
from selenium import selenium

def main():
    sel = selenium('localhost', 4444, '*firefox', 'http://www.sina.com.cn/')
    sel.start()
    try:
        sel.open('http://www.sina.com.cn/')
    except Exception, e:
        print e
    else:
        print sel.get_title()
    sel.close()
    sel.stop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It is very easy to understand. What I really want is to close all windows that selenium opens. I've tried close() and stop(), but they all don't work.

Comment: are there any errors in the Selenium RC?

Comment: only this looks like an error:
17:07:47.894 WARN - Caution: '/usr/bin/firefox-bin': file is a script file, not a real executable.  The browser environment is no longer fully under RC control

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar case  where my program opened many windows when scraping a webpage. here is a sample code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import webbrowser
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
print "Browser fired-up!"
driver.get("https://www.something.com/")
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

while True:

    try:
        playlink = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div/a")
        playlink.click()
        time.sleep(3)
    except NoSuchElementException: 
        print "playlink Element not found "
    else:
        backbutton = driver.find_element_by_id("back-to-bing-text")
        backbutton.click()

    try:
        quizlink = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/ul/li[1]/a/span/span[1]")
        quizlink.click()
    except NoSuchElementException: 
        print "quiz1 Element not found "
    else:
        print "quiz1 clicked"

    driver.quit()
```

The "driver.close()" bugged me for a week as I believed it would close all the windows. "driver.quit()" is to terminate all the process and close all the windows.

Answer (score 1):

I've fix this problem.
It happens because I installed firefox-bin not firefox.
Now I've removed firefox-bin and have installed firefox, it works now.
stop() will close all windows that selenium opened.

Thank you for your reminds [AutomatedTester](https://stackoverflow.com/users/108827/automatedtester)

Answer (score 0):

I may suggest to make a system command with python to close the firefox windows

Bussiere